# MySql create trigger error 1064

Tags: mysql

the sql I wrote is as below:

```
create

trigger test_schedule_trigger after update on tw_task
as
update tw_test_schedule test, tw_task task
set test.name = task.name,test.`type`=task.`type`,test.is_deleted=task.is_deleted,test.gmt_modified=task.gmt_modified;
where tw_test_schedule.task_id = tw_task.id;
```

the error description is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where tw_test_schedule.task_id = tw_task.id' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Try remove the ; before the `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

You have a `;` semicolon at the end of your `set` line:

```
                                                right here
                                                     v
set blah, blah, test.gmt_modified = task.gmt_modified;
where blah ...
```

This is terminating the statement, meaning that the `where` is not really valid SQL. Just get rid of that semicolon.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, howerer it remained unsolved. The description after I modified is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'asupdate tw_test_schedule test, tw_task task
set test.name = task.name,test.`' at line 3"

Comment: @eric, then check your string near that point. I'm pretty certain `asupdate` is not valid SQL either :-)

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, i'm a newcomer of mysql. i made a modification but it turned out to commit the same mistake.`create trigger test_schedule_trigger
after update on tw_task
for each row
begin
 update tw_test_schedule test, tw_task task
 set test.name = task.name,test.`type`=task.`type`,test.is_deleted=task.is_deleted,test.gmt_modified=task.gmt_modified
 where test.task_id=task.id
end;`The description is You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end' at line 8.

Comment: @eric, you don't need begin/end in this case because it's a single statement. But, if you *do* use it, every statement within it must be terminated with a semicolon. That means putting one **before** the `end`.